# pass variable from sub-make to main make

Tags: makefile

up make level could export variable X, and sub-make could use the variable X. is there a way do opposite? I want sub make pass variable to upper level make.

following code won't work.

Makefile

```
a:
     make -f eval_X.mk 
     echo $(X)

eval_X.mk

b:
      $(eval X=123)
```

Comment: There is no way for a sub-process, of any kind, to change anything about a parent process, of any kind.  Make is no exception to this.  This is a restriction enforced by the operating system.  The only way to do it would be for the sub-make to write to a file or something, then the parent make would have to read that file and set variables based on its contents.

Comment: yeah, I thought the way to write to a file. just want to see if there is a  simple way. thank you.

Comment: That's a bit too strong, @MadScientist, albeit true enough for the purposes of the question.

Comment: Well, it is pretty much true.  A child cannot affect the memory of the parent.  Of course, the parent can affect its own memory and it's possible for the parent to provide some mechanism for the child to _ask_ the parent to make changes: a file like I suggested, or a pipe or shared memory or other such thing.  But that requires both the parent and child to agree on that method and protocol, and there's no standard or generic way to do this, so it's not useful unless both parent and child are specifically written to work together this way.

Answer (score 0):

Each make target commands run as a sub shell. So there is no existience of variable outside single command. Take a look at this if it helps:

```
VAR_X = 11

test:
    $(eval VAR_X=123)
    @echo ${VAR_X}      // output : 123

test2:
    @echo ${VAR_X}      // output : 11
```

Also, you can use target dependencies to set the var:

```
a: $(eval X=123)
    echo $(X)          // output : 123
```